# How to solve invalid symbol coordinate error

Tags: r

I am trying to run a line of code from a manual but each time I get this error **Error in symbols(x = coords[, 1], y = coords[, 2], bg = vertex.color,  : invalid symbol coordinates**

Now, this is my code

```
LGHomDf_P1 <- bridgeHomologues(pseudohom_stack = P1_homologues_5,
linkage_df = SN_DN_P1,
LOD_threshold = 5,
automatic_clustering = TRUE,
LG_number = 7,
parentname = "P1",
log = "Logfile_tetra.Rmd")
```

I have been reading some post on the forum but I could not find any information.
Moreover, I do not think I have to use igraph because it is not mentioned at all in the manual.

Moreover the package that I am using is called PolyMappeR.

Comment: Can you specify your question? It does not even show the function you are using...

Comment: The function is called `bridgeHomologues` 

When I try to run it, I do get this error. Instead it should show a graph where homologues are represented

Comment: I don't know that function (what package are you using? *you should include that in your question*, since it is not `igraph`), but my guess is that you are passing an object as an argument that is improperly structured.